# Weird white border top left of whole tkinter application

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the first tkinter application I've ever made and I'm sure there are other issues with it but it works well for me. The only issue I have is for some reason on my 4k monitor there is a little white border on the top left side of the application. This does not appear on my 1080p monitor. Edit: It appears this is due to adding an icon. When I have an icon it happens. When I remove the icon part it goes away. This obviously isn't a solution though since I still want an icon for my application. I'll leave a picture of the issue and the code for the application here.

[I'm not allowed to post images yet so here is a link for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seDeM.png)

```py
from tkinter import *

#Main Section
app = Tk()
app.title('Rust Furnace Calculator')
app.iconbitmap('Rust.ico')
app.configure(background='#33393B')
app.resizable(False, False)
app.geometry("500x500")

#Program Loop
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You've posted a huge amount of code, much of it irrelevant to the question being asked. Please try to reduce it down to a [mcve]. For example, remove one of the labels and entry widgets. Does the problem persist? If so, remove another, and so on. Also, since you're asking about the visuals we don't need any of the code that does computations. or resetting, or any thing else that's not strictly related to reproducing the problem.

Comment: Okay I deleted literally everything from it and it appears the instant I add an icon to the application that is when it happens. But obviously I want an icon for my application so removing it isn't really a solution